# Can not retrieve data between domain and sub domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cross-domain

I have an Ajax request on a domian xyz.com and I am performing an 
Ajax request from xyz.com to pull data from abc.xyz.com

```
var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://abc.mno.com/vending/mainvending.php",
        data: {vlu:"1"},
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        cache: false,               
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        error: function(  jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
               { 
                    alert("error : " + errorThrown + " text :"+textStatus + " j :" +jqXHR.status);
                    // alert(jqXHR.responseText);
               },
        success: Succeeded,
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) { }
});
```

but I keep getting this error which is consoled out in the browser (Chrome)

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://abc.xyz.com/vending/mainvending.php. Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

In the mainvending.php the codes are as follows

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
require_once 'vendors.php';

if(!empty($_POST)){
    /** Other codes follow **/
}else{
    /** Other codes follow **/
}
?>
```

what am I not doing or what am I doing wrong? The domain name is xyz and the domain I am retrieving data from is of a sub domain could that be the issue and how do I go around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says that the server isn't allowing you to send a cache-control header.

You are doing that here:

> ```
> headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
> ```

… cache-control is a **response** header, so it makes no sense to include it in a request.

Remove that line.

(Alternatively, you could add it to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header that you are already setting).

Comment: Thanks. didn't notice that. Will delete the question now

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these headers

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following two things:-

1. Remove this key-value pair from your AJAX config

   `headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },`
2. Add `cache-control` header to your PHP code to allow it.

   `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, cache-control');`